# React: Click button to load image from static location in directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

When the user clicks "Sample 1" button on the screen, it should load and display an image located locally.

Here is what I tried but it does not work

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import image_1 from "../../static_media/1.png"
import image_2 from "../../static_media/2.png"
import {Container, Image} from "react-bootstrap";


class Classifier extends Component {
    state = {
        files: [],
        isLoading: false,
        recentImage: null,
    }


    handleClick = (e) => {

        const ImageData = [image_1, image_2]

        const FILES = {
            "image_1": [{
                name: "image_1",
                size: "100",
                image: ImageData[0]
            }],
            "image_2": [{
                name: "image_2",
                size: "200",
                image: ImageData[1]
            }],
            "image_3": [{
                name: "image_3",
                size: "300",
                image: ImageData[1]
            }],
        }

        // you can now use this value to load your images
        const prefix = e.target.dataset.prefix; // 1
        this.setState({
            files: [],
            isLoading: true,
            recentImage: null
        })
        this.loadImage(FILES[`image_${prefix}`])
    }

    loadImage = (files) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                files,
                isLoading: false
            }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.files[0])
            })
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        const files = this.state.files.map(file => (
            <li key={file.name}>
                {file.name} - {file.size} bytes
            </li>
        ));
        return (

            <Container>

                <button
                    data-prefix="1"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
                    className="btn btn-primary">
                    Sample 1
                </button>
                <aside>
                    {files}
                </aside>

                <div className="img-fluid">
                    {this.state.files.length > 0 &&
                    <Image
                        src={URL.createObjectURL(this.state.files[0])}
                        height='400' rounded/>
                    }
                </div>
            </Container>


        )
    }
}

export default Classifier;
```

I get an error

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload
> resolution failed.
>
> 78 |    79 |     {this.state.files.length
>
> > 0 &&   80 |     <Image
> > 81 |         src={URL.createObjectURL(this.state.files[0])}
> > | ^  82 |         height='400' rounded/>   83 |     }   84 |

Ideally, I would like to create an actual image object so I am able to send this image to the Django REST API.

Comment: It looks like there's a typo inside of `handleClick` where the `setState` second parameter isn't inside the actual function call.

Comment: @JosephAdam you can use `data-attributes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Blob or File object for URL.createObjectURL().
(You can read about URL.createObjectURL() here [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL))

Simplest way to create a Blob object is use Fetch API.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import image_1 from "../../static_media/1.png"
import image_2 from "../../static_media/2.png"
import {Container, Image} from "react-bootstrap";


class Classifier extends Component {
    state = {
        files: [],
        isLoading: false,
        recentImage: null,
    }


    handleClick = async (e) => {

        const ImageData = [image_1, image_2]

        const FILES = {
            "image_1": [{
                name: "image_1",
                size: "100",
                image: await fetch(ImageData[0]).then(res => res.blob()) 
            }],
            "image_2": [{
                name: "image_2",
                size: "200",
                image: await fetch(ImageData[1]).then(res => res.blob())
            }],
            "image_3": [{
                name: "image_3",
                size: "300",
                image: await fetch(ImageData[1]).then(res => res.blob())
            }],
        }

        // you can now use this value to load your images
        const prefix = e.target.dataset.prefix; // 1
        this.setState({
            files: [],
            isLoading: true,
            recentImage: null
        })
        this.loadImage(FILES[`image_${prefix}`])
    }

    loadImage = (files) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                files,
                isLoading: false
            }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.files[0])
            })
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        const files = this.state.files.map(file => (
            <li key={file.name}>
                {file.name} - {file.size} bytes
            </li>
        ));
        return (

            <Container>

                <button
                    data-prefix="1"
                    onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
                    className="btn btn-primary">
                    Sample 1
                </button>
                <aside>
                    {files}
                </aside>

                <div className="img-fluid">
                    {this.state.files.length > 0 &&
                    <Image
                        src={URL.createObjectURL(this.state.files[0].image)}
                        height='400' rounded/>
                    }
                </div>
            </Container>


        )
    }
}

export default Classifier;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually specify the images info or you'll need extra steps to get file size dynamically.

```
const FILES = {
    "image_1": [{
        name: "image_1",
        size: "100",
        image: require("../../static_media/1.png").default
    }],
    "image_2": [{
        name: "image_2",
        size: "200",
        image: require("../../static_media/2.png").default
    }],
}
```

Add a data attribute and click event to each button,

```
<button 
       ...
       data-prefix="1" 
       onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}> Sample 1</button>



    handleClick = (e) => {
        // you can now use this value to load your images
        const prefix = e.target.dataset.prefix; // 1
        this.setState({
            files: [],
            isLoading: true,
            recentImage: null
        })
        this.loadImage(FILES[`image_${prefix}`])
    }
```

Comment: @JosephAdam I think you already have an array the contain all  images with their metadata (name, size) ?

Comment: sorry it does not solve it! I am not able to load it and display it. I added a bounty.